# UWP and WinForm Desktop Bridge

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, desktop-bridge

I've UWP application and I want to use some features from win form application in my UWP application. I'm doing communication between two application via app service and desktop bridge to pack win form application. My requirement is my UWP application should run on Window server 2016.
I create build using desktop bridge and it's running fine on my window 10 with latest update but when I installed on window server 2016 UWP application started but when it starts win form application it gave following error.

[image: Error upon starting winform application]

Is Desktop bridge working on Window Server 2016 or not ?

Comment: What's the app's target and min version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT My UWP application target version is Window 10, version 1903 and min version is Window 10 Anniversary Update. Winform target framework is .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I run the application on Window Server 2019 it worked fine there.

Comment: Ok, why you want to run the desktop-bridge in server 2016? can you run it in latest version ?

Comment: And above screen show, it is missing file with specific path, have you checked if the folder contains the file from above path?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Our team has old window 2016 server and do not want to migrate to new one. Yes I checked the path file is there.

Comment: it's hard to say, I have not found related document explain this, I will discuss with team, I will update below, there may be a delay.

Comment: I have tested within my Server 2016, it could work well and the winform project .Net Framework 4.6.1,  because my server has not install 4.7.2. Please try to uninstall previous app, and rebuild new version

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Did you tried with UWP + winform through desktop bridge ?

Comment: Yep, I package the app with windows application package template

Comment: If you use winform as  desktop extension for uwp app, we suggest you use windows application package project to integrate  them

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I created new window application packaging project and add reference of new blank winform application inside. It is giving same error on server. I think there is some permission issue in server. I'm using server on VM.

Comment: could you mind share [mcve] for us, I will test base on your demo.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tried with this simple example. This was also not worked. I added code on google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YX-bON-8G1w-B7qRossygo6dMfIgMlv8/view?usp=sharing

It just run window from with hello world lable

Comment: I make appx and install successfully with you provide sample  in server 2016 just now. it works well in my [envirment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsuKM.png).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I installed VS in Window Server 2016 and run the same application that i shared with you it gave this error do you know about it "DEP0600: Deployment failed. EntryPointNotFoundException - Unable to find an entry point named 'IsWow64GuestMachineSupported' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'. [0x80131523]"

Comment: it's hard to detect the issue, we can't reproduce your problem, could you try to install the app within other machine?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Which VS version you used on Window Server 2016 for build last time ?

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2019 build the package in windows 10 enterprise, and deploy the package with powershell in window server 2016